# Disable Spring logging while using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot

I'm running my SpringBoot application using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringCoreConfig.class);
```

and SpringCoreConfig class is only:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ocado.cfc.optimisation")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringCoreConfig {}
```

but my application output is unreadable due to logging level DEBUG.
I tried to set logging level to INFO in application.properties:

```
logging.level.root=OFF
```

But it doesn't change anything.
How can I change logging level to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the spring logging level to WARN (or any level) using `application.properties` as shown below, you can refer the Spring doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) on this.

```
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
```